# Maximum of $a_1a_2+a_2a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}a_n+a_na_1$ where $\sum a_i$ is constant

Tags: inequality

Non-negative real numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ are such that $a_1+\ldots +a_n=k$, where $k$ is a constant.  Find the maximum value of
$$a_1a_2+a_2a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}a_n+a_na_1$$
For $n=2$ we can reach $\frac{k^2}{2}$ with $a_1=a_2=\frac{k}{2}$.

For $n=3$ we can reach $\frac{k^2}{3}$ with $a_1=a_2=a_3=\frac{k}{3}$.

For $n\geq 4$, I suspect $\frac{k^2}{4}$ is the limit, at least when $n$ is even, since we can split $k$ into
$$S=a_1+a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}$$
$$k-S=a_2+a_4+\ldots+a_n$$
Notice that the product $S(k-S)$ contains all the terms of the expression we want to maximise.  In other words
$$a_1a_2+a_2a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}a_n+a_na_1$$
$$\leq (a_1+a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1})(a_2+a_4+\ldots+a_n)$$
$$=S(k-S)=\frac{k^2}{4}-(S-\frac{k}{2})^2\leq\frac{k^2}{4}$$

Comment: You can do better than k^2/n: by letting a_1=a_2=k/2, you will obtain k^2/2 for n=2 and k^2/4 otherwise, which is better than k^2/n for n>4. I believe you cannot obtain better than this (and better than k^2/3 for n=3), but I don't see the proof for now.

Comment: @AshtonParks Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_1%2B%5Cldots%20%2Ba_n%3Dk%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24a_1a_2%2Ba_2a_3%2B%5Cldots%2Ba_%7Bn-1%7Da_n%2Ba_na_1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Amaximum&p=1), I found $k=1$ handled in the AoPS [can you use the adjustment method](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1632255p10250452), & the somewhat related (but also more general) [Maximum of $\sum_{cyc}x_1x_2x_3\cdots x_k$ given $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=a$ for non-negative $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ for a positive integer $n$ and $1<k<n$](/q/3769559).

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Thanks @bdx77.  You're right, $\frac{k^2}{4}$ is a better limit.  I've updated the question with this in mind.

Comment: Thank you @John Omielan, I hadn't heard of Approach Zero before.  Seems useful.

Comment: @AshtonParks You're welcome. See [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) for some info about using Approach0, as well as about other methods to search on this site.

Comment: Also, see a related problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1671756p10658926, I gave a proof there: Let $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ $(n\geq 2)$ be  nonnegative real numbers such that $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=n.$ Prove that $$a_1a_2+a_2a_3+
\cdots+a_{n-1}a_n+a_na_1\leq max\{n,\frac{n^2}{4}\}.$$

Comment: (Cont.) My proof for that problem: If $n = 2i$ ($i \ge 2$), we have
$a_1a_2 + a_2a_3 + \cdots + a_na_1
\le (a_1 + a_3 + \cdots + a_{2i-1})(a_2+a_4+\cdots + a_{2i})
\le \frac{(a_1+ a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^2}{4}$;
If $n = 2i + 1$ ($i\ge 2$), WLOG, assume that $a_{2i+1}=\min(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{2i+1})$. We have
$a_1a_2 + a_2a_3 + \cdots + a_na_1
\le (a_1 + a_3 + \cdots + a_{2i+1})(a_2+a_4+\cdots + a_{2i}) - a_1 (a_4 - a_{2i+1}) \le \frac{(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n)^2}{4}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We claim that for $n\ge 4$, given that $\sum_{j=1}^nx_j=k$ and identifying $x_{n+1}:=x_1$, we have $$\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j}x_{j+1}\le \frac{k^2}{4}$$
Towards a proof, we divide the problem into 2 cases.

If $n=2k,\ k\in\mathbb N$ (that is $n$ is even), we just have

$$\sum_{j=1}^n x_{j}x_{j+1}\le (x_1+x_3+\cdots+x_{2k-1})(x_2+x_4+\cdots+x_{2k})\le \left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{k^2}{4}$$

where the second inequality follows from the AM-GM inequality.

If $n=2k+1,\ k\in\mathbb N$ (that is $n$ is odd), rearrange the elements such that $x_1$ is the least element (if not, then just cyclically permute the elements until it is, and then note that cyclic permutations do not change any of the summations). Then
\begin{align*}(x_1+x_3+\cdots +x_{2k+1})(x_2+x_4+\cdots +x_{2k})&\ge \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_jx_{j+1}+x_{2k+1}x_{2}\\&\ge \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_jx_{j+1}+x_{2k+1}x_1\\&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_jx_{j+1}\end{align*}

Hence $$\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_jx_{j+1}\le (x_1+x_3+\cdots +x_{2k+1})(x_2+x_4+\cdots +x_{2k})\le \left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^nx_{j}}{2}\right)^2=\frac{k^2}{4}$$

where again the second inequality comes from the AM-GM inequality.

Thus for all cases, the inequality is proven. That this is the maximum value is seen by just putting in $$(x_1,\ x_2,\dots,\ x_n)=\left( \frac{k}{2},\ \frac{k}{2},\ 0,\ 0,\ \cdots,\ 0\right)$$

at which point the bound is reached.

Comment: You don'T know calculus then.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Very nice solution, @HackR.

Answer (score -1):

I use the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Maximize $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=x_1x_2+x_2x_3+...+x_{n-1}x_n+x_nx_1$

Subject to $g(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=x_1+x_2+...+x_{n-1}+x_n=k$

$f_{x_i}=\lambda g_{x_i}$ for $i=1,2,...,n$ gives $x_i+x_{i+2}=\lambda$ for all $i=1,...,n-2$ and $x_{n-1}+x_1=\lambda$ and $x_n+x_2=\lambda$. Those last two equations are extremely confusing... So, from the constraint condition we find $x_i=\frac{k}{n}$ for all $i$, since the linear system has non-zero determinant and there is a unique solution. But then $f(\frac{k}{n},\frac{k}{n},...,\frac{k}{n})=n\frac{k^2}{n^2}=\frac{k^2}{n}$. This is not the answer unless $n=4$! Did we find the minumum? No. The minumum is zero. Anyway. The question asks the maximum. How can I save this method?

I hope this explanation works: Therefore, the maximum happens on the boundry of the closed region ($x_i\geq 0$) that the function $f$ is defined. This boundry is $x_i=0$ hyperplanes. Taking $x_n=0,x_{n-1}=...=x_3=0$ inductively we can reduce the problem to: Maximize $x_1x_2$, subject to $x_1+x_2=k$. But the answer of this question is well-known and it is $\frac{k^2}{4}$.

Explanation of the induction here for $n=4$: On hyperplane $x_4=0$, we have $$x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_4+x_4x_1=x_1x_2+x_2x_3=(x_1+x_3)x_2=x'_1x_2$$ with the condition $x'_1+x_2=k$. I hope this is convincing for the hackers.

Comment: The boundary points have one coordinate equal to zero. How did you do induction?

Comment: They may have other coordinates equal to zero. For example, the hyperplane $x_n=0$  has the point  $(*,*,...,*,0,0)$.

Comment: I agree with sir Mariano. There seems to be something missing from the induction, because I am not sure I follow? Maybe flesh it out a bit more?

Comment: It is calculus. You don't like.

Comment: AGM can not solve all extrema problems. Only special problems.

Comment: I will show you induction step for $n=4$. You can generalize.

Comment: I think the backlash here is more regarding the unclear answer than people "not liking calculus". First, your use of Lagrange Multipliers ignores the non-negativity constraint on each $x_i$ with no reason why. The rest of the answer is a bit confusing too, it could use line-breaks and less phrases like " Those last two equations are extremely confusing... So, from the constraint condition[...]"

Comment: @jDAQ You can choose the region and it has a boundry.

Comment: @jDAQ I think an effort for a second way of solution is not a  bad thing. I understand AGM people. They go to mathematical olympiads. But, there are calculus olympiads too.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. It is nice to have an alternative approach, but your answer is confusing. If you could clear it up maybe people would be convinced/understand it and upvote it.